# Intellisense Xamarin Forms não funciona - Visual Studio Enterprise with Update 3

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin-forms, intellisense

Instalei o VS com o Xamarin mas o Intellisense nos arquivos XAML não está funcionando corretamente. Em algumas partes do código ele mostra a lista de sugestões conforme imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que em outras partes do código ele não mostra a lista com todos os itens (imagem abaixo).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele também está abrindo a o XAML com o Editor XML (imagem abaixo), mas não deveria ser com o XAML Designer?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem tem alguma susgestão para resolver ou contornar esse problema?

Agradeço a todos dês de já.

Answer (score 1):

estava tendo o mesmo problema e o resolvi da seguinte forma:

Atualizei o Xamarin para sua ultima versão como solicitado pelo próprio Visual Studio 2015

Reiniciei o Visual Studio

Botão direito do mouse no arquivo xaml e cliquei em "Open With..", que por padrão estava marcado "Source Code Text(Editor) With Encoding" e mudei para "Automatic Editor Selector (XML) para ser o Default.

Repare que essa linha  deve estar completamente azul se estiver funcionando pois se estiver com algum elemento em vermelho significa que o Intellisense do xml que está trabalhando e não do xaml.

Abraços.